# OAuth2 Authentification Django and MSexchange

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, exchange-server

I am building a Django App where users have to be able to send emails with their specific exchange mail address. I think I need OAuth2 for that. However MS support and all other resources I found state that I need to register my app in Azure AD. But I don't have an Azure AD. I do have access to the Microsoft 365 admin center. Do I have to register my App there or generate a specific token?